# Is there a way to re-use a template literal in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I'm trying to re-use a template literal in javascript.

This isn't working:

```
let int;
let temp= `Number is: ${int}`;
console.log(temp)
// Number is: undefined
int = 1;
console.log(temp)
// Number is: undefined
int = 2;
console.log(temp)
// Number is: undefined
```

I thought that changing `int` variable will dynamicaly change in the template. but i learned otherwise :D

Is it even possible and if so what is the right way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: `cronTimeTemp` - What is this?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashattsorry my mistake i simplified my example and forgot to change the name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply make it to be returned by a *function*:

```js
let int;
let temp= () => `Number is: ${int}`;
console.log(temp())
// Number is: undefined
int = 1;
console.log(temp())
// Number is: 1
int = 2;
console.log(temp())
// Number is: 2
```

Comment: You could pass `int` as a parameter instead of taking closure over the variable

Comment: As I do not know what's the use for the OP code, I prefer to point out the problem with the minimum edit possible to the OP code so he can focus on it.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to create a function for this.

```js
function getTemp(int) {
  return `Number is: ${int}`;
}


let int;
console.log(getTemp(int))
// Number is: undefined
int = 1;
console.log(getTemp(int))
// Number is: undefined
int = 2;
console.log(getTemp(int))
// Number is: undefined
```

Comment: or, since we're in ES6 : `const getTemp = int => \`Number is: ${int}\``

Comment: Is possible but not recommended. It gets uneasy to read really quickly. @JeremyThille

Comment: Only to those who stick with ES5 and don't write ES6 code :)

Comment: I like a lot about ES6 but this is really bad style imo. At least make it something like that: `const getTemp = (int) => {\n \`Number is: ${int}\` \n}`. @JeremyThille

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)

```js
let temp= (num) => `Number is: ${num}`;

console.log(temp `1`);
console.log(temp `2`)
```