# What is the difference between the following two code blocks

Tags: javascript

```
function greet(name) {
  let hours = 11;
  let time = "";

  if (hours >= 4 && hours < 12) {
    time = "Good Morning";
  } else {
    time = "hi";
  }

  return `${time}, ${name}`;
}

greet("Ali");
```

The output is correct. It output is `"Good morning, Ali"`

But when I change the the return statement, just like below. It returns `"  , Ali"`.

```
function greet(name) {
  let hours = 11;
  let time = "";
  let result = `${time}, ${name}`;

  if (hours >= 4 && hours < 12) {
    time = "Good Morning";
  } else {
    time = "hi";
  }

  return result;
}

greet("Ali");
```

Could anyone please explain this?

Comment: `result` is created first and never modified after the updation of time in second.

Comment: That  `let result=..` calculates the 'result' *immediately* using current values. It doesn't set up any relation that automatically follows changes in variables

Comment: A related question is here [Is there a way to re-use a template literal in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112552/is-there-a-way-to-re-use-a-template-literal-in-javascript)

Comment: I think it was wrong to close the question as 'caused by typos'. The code in the second example has been intentionally written as it is and is certainly no typo. The OP asked why it doesn't work. That's more of a problem of understanding the mechanisms. OP's expectation is probably a behavior like in an Excel formula, which will also update the cell value if any of the other referred cells change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is when you use the variable `time` (the naming of which is somewhat ironic in this case).  Look at the first code:

```
// 1) initialize time to a default value
let time = "";

// 2) set the correct value
if (hours >= 4 && hours < 12) {
  time = "Good Morning";
} else {
  time = "hi";
}

// 3) use the value
return `${time}, ${name}`;
```

Now look at the second example:

```
// 1) initialize time to a default value
let time = "";

// 2) use the value
let result = `${time}, ${name}`;

// 3) set the correct value
if (hours >= 4 && hours < 12) {
  time = "Good Morning";
} else {
  time = "hi";
}
```

See how you're *using* the value before you've *set* the value?  You've reversed those two steps.  Un-reverse them:

```
// 1) initialize time to a default value
let time = "";

// 2) set the correct value
if (hours >= 4 && hours < 12) {
  time = "Good Morning";
} else {
  time = "hi";
}

// 3) use the value
let result = `${time}, ${name}`;
```

If your expectation is that the use of a variable will automatically re-calculate itself if that variable ever changes, that expectation is false.  This line of code executes *once*:

```
let result = `${time}, ${name}`;
```

After it's executed, the result is stored in the variable `result`.  If `time` or `name` ever change, the system isn't going to go back to this line of code and execute it again.  The value in `result` never changes.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the different outputs in your two versions of the `greet` function is the order of your code execution and the way JavaScript works.

In the first version, you set the `time` variable based on the `hours` condition before creating the `result` variable. So, when you return `${time}, ${name}`, it correctly evaluates the `time` variable to "Good Morning" and then combines it with `name`.

In the second version, you set the `result` variable before you set the `time` variable. Therefore, `time` is still an empty string when you create `result`, and it stays that way because the conditional statement that sets `time` to "Good Morning" or "hi" only happens after `result` has been assigned. As a result, `result` is initialized with an empty string followed by `name`, which is why you get "  , Ali."

To fix this issue in the second version, you should move the creation of `result` after the conditional statement that sets the `time` variable to "Good Morning" or "hi." This way, the `time` variable will have the correct value before you create `result`, resulting in the desired output of "Good Morning, Ali."